# how to pass parameters in jasper report using codeigniter view

Tags: php, codeigniter, jasper-reports

I have rendered jasper report from codeigniter using PHPJasperXML library. I want to know how can i pass parameters to that report from my view. I am not getting the value in $is_active variable.It becomes always 0 even when i checked my checkbox.

**My View**

```
<div class="form-group mb-2 col-lg-6">
     <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
     <input class="custom-control-input" id="is-active" type="checkbox" name="is-active">
      <label class="custom-control-label pt-1" for="is-active">Is Active</label>
     </div>
</div>
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>MyController/getReport" target="_blank"><button name="btn_report" id="btn_report" type="button">Report</button></a>
```

**My Controller**

```
public function getReport()
{
    if ($this->input->post('is-active') == true) {
        $is_active = 1;
    } else {
        $is_active = 0;
    }
    $path=base_url()."Assets/reports/report.jrxml";
    $params=array($is_active);
    $this->mymodel->showReport($path,$params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the code can be wrapped by `<form></form>` ?

```html
<div class="form-group mb-2 col-lg-6">
     <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
     <input class="custom-control-input" id="is-active" type="checkbox" name="is-active">
      <label class="custom-control-label pt-1" for="is-active">Is Active</label>
     </div>
</div>
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>MyController/getReport" target="_blank"><button name="btn_report" id="btn_report" type="button">Report</button></a>
```

Try this:

```html
<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>MyController/getReport" method="post">
    <div class="form-group mb-2 col-lg-6">
         <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
         <input class="custom-control-input" id="is-active" type="checkbox" name="is-active">
          <label class="custom-control-label pt-1" for="is-active">Is Active</label>
         </div>
    </div>
    <input name="btn_report" id="btn_report" type="submit" value="Report"/>
</form>
```

Comment: yeah this code is already wrapped by <form></form> but i dont want to do this by submitting the form because on submit this form i am calling other function.

Comment: so $this->input->post('is-active')  can't  receive the value you want to send. because you reach the function by <a> tag

Comment: i want the report on new tab.I have another submit button in the form for submitting the data into database. i want use the get report button for just render the report thats why in form tag i cannot use action for my report function

Comment: if you just want to pass a simple sign ,try add value to the url,like"<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>MyController/getReport/1" >xxx</a>,then you can get it by"public function getReport($is_active){...}"https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#passing-uri-segments-to-your-methods

Comment: only use <a>tag jump to a url won't carry any data from form with him